# VS Intellisense - Autocomplete - Show member type and origin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

Straight to the point: Is it possible to change the way Visual Studio Intellisense autocomplete pop-up lists all the members? Or are there any (free) extensions that can do such a thing?

In the autocomplete pop-up, no information about members is provided, only the name. I would like to also know the type and origin.

Currently, more details about the member are shown only when that member is selected, which is not what I'm looking for. Imagine having 100+ members ...

**Example:**

In the screenshot (from VisualStudio) below, one can see that no type or origin for properties is provided, only the name.

[image]

In the screenshot (from NetBeans) below, one can see that the type (?) and origin (ChildClass/ParentClass) is provided.

[image]

I would like to achieve such informative listing of members in Visual Studio. Is that possible? Maybe even sorting of members in a way that they are sorted by origin: first the ChildClass properties, then ParentClass properties, etc.., and not always by the name.

Comment: You can have a look at the VS 2017 RC and now we can filter and predictive Intellisense, for the detail information, please check this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/11/29/visual-studio-2017-rc-new-and-improved-features/

Comment: I'm waiting for a full release. Can filter settings be saved, or must it be done manually every single time?

Comment: The filter cannot be saved and you need to choose different options every time per your requirement, as far as I know, the full release of VS 2017 will release recently.

Comment: I see. Well, having to do it every single time is painful and kind of defeats the purpose of "autocomplete". It's sad that all other IDEs have this feature, but VS doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

What version of VS are you using. I'm using VS2015 and it certainly has what you need:
[image]

Comment: Not constructive

Comment: why and how to be?

Comment: This is not what I was asking for. Here you have to select a single member to list more information. I want that on the list itself. Imagine having 100 properties and searching through them... would be nice to also have them sorted not alphabetically, but by the origin, like I stated in the question.

Comment: oh...sorry for misunderstood you. but I think VS is always beyond my expectations, I'm happy with it as it is.

Comment: I am too. This is the only thing that I like better in other IDEs: NetBeans, AndroidStudio, Eclipse, ... All other IDEs have that feature. It's kind of awkward that Visual Studio doesn't have it, because it's miles beyond all other IDEs in other aspects.

Comment: If I have to find the signatures from numerous methods I often go to msdn, which is far more documented and handy than other languages.